# script never completes last line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wrote this script to get some files off a webcam server. The files, are all downloaded, but when I was running the script, the last line never ends, even after the file was downloaded. So, I would like to know why. Why did this script never terminate? The `wget` command got the last file, but did not exit.

```
#!/bin/bash 
x="127.0.0.1"  
z=0
while read line
do z=$(($z+1));
echo $x${line//};
wget $x${line//};
done < "/home/jay/Desktop/PINGS"
read
```

So why doesn't this script terminate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last line contains just `read`.

Read the `help` page of `read`, from `help read`:

```
Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.
```

So unless you give input to `read` via STDIN, it will be blocked indefinitely.

In a script, `read` is normally used to read lines(s) from file(s) or to take user input (like your case).

Comment: I totally spaced out on that. thanks for pointing it out.